# Too small search bar and the search icon/magnifying glass is shown twice while viewing sites in portrait mode on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, responsive-design

The search bar (with drop-down) in the top bar isn't responsive.

It also is duplicated, which means it takes up an unnecessarily large amount of space on Stack Overflow with the AI text:

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are now two useless Search icons. This is happening both here on MSE and on MSO. It looks ok in the Desktop Site view.

Comment: Not only on Meta, it's on all SE sites.

Comment: @PM2Ring Luckily I had a Meta.SE tab opened on my phone's browser before the update (actually I have 100+ tabs open). It looks like there were still two search icons before, but previously when you press the search button, the search bar would appear below the top bar.

Comment: @Neumann Indeed! It took a while to propagate to the other sites. (I only checked half a dozen other sites before my previous comment, though).

Comment: I have two search icons, and they push my site selector off the right edge of my mobile display. Android/Firefox.

Comment: And this doesn't work! (Android; Cross Validated).

Comment: On my iPhone 13 running iOS 15.4.1 and Safari, the menu [looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twWo2.jpg).

Comment: came here to Meta with the intention to report the same bug (+1). I'm using Chrome in a Samsung Galaxy A54 with Android 14. Can't see what's written inside of the search and this happens in at least in StackOverflow. Bible Hermeneutics, in the Meta communities as well as here in Meta StackExchange.

Comment: I think this problem is dependent on the screen resolution.

Comment: What is the second search icon supposed to be doing? It seems to switch the search box width between narrow and narrower. What's the point of that?

Comment: @cubick Yes, but it's complicated because CSS pixels don't necessarily correspond to actual screen pixels. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16050018/4014959 So a high-res mobile browser window can "appear" to have a relatively small width in pixels to the CSS & JavaScript on a website. Note that the 2nd Search icon disappears when the phone is in landscape orientation. That's *probably* because the landscape width is larger, but the page *may* also detect orientation through a media query.

Comment: Now I need to turn my phone horizontally to search something. What a wonderful feature. Rollback please, it makes SO site moderation more difficult while searching a dup. (Samsung Galaxy A50 + Firefox)

Comment: I'm annoyed that this change to the UI was rolled out without adequate tests to ensure that it's responsive on phones (apart from iPhones). But I'm baffled that it was rolled out at the end of business hours, New York time.

Comment: Here's [how it looks when I press the search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqN8j.jpg).

Comment: @PM2Ring No time for April Fools, no time for software testing.

Comment: Did this bug just appear yesterday? Looking into who dun it.

Comment: What is also annoying is if you really try to type in this small box some text, say "search", you end up searching "hcreas" instead. Not too bad for a April Fool's joke.

Comment: Some combinations of tapping the two icons completely hose the screen - overlaying a bunch of text on a transparent background. Fire the AI tester!

Comment: @Piper I reported it as soon as I saw it.

Comment: @Piper just follow the commits and it should be there.

Comment: We had a hand full of commits @ShadowWizardLoveZelda but we found it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Piper so, Whodunit?

Comment: On my phone, Samsung Galaxy S23+, using the stock Samsung browser, rotating the phone to landscape does not increase the size of the search bar at all, it is still squished to near nothing. But the drop down menu does have room to resize to normal.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda A very tiny team trying to do big things on a large network. I know these bugs are a huge headache for you all, but I appreciate you all reporting them and giving grace to the teams trying to make a big improvements.

Comment: As of now, this seemed to have been fixed. Thanks to the team working behind.

Comment: @Piper thanks, and a side note: your network profile is not synched with the other profiles, I see there were some changes, that aren't reflected there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks fixed now!

[image: Normal drop-down]

Answer (score 4):

I'm on Android/Firefox, and the biggest problem this causes me is that the "Community switcher" is not visible, and thus not accessible.

The work around I've discovered is that if I tap the second Search icon, the switcher pops into view.

Update: As suggested by Laurel, one can just swipe-scroll the top icon row and bring it in to view. I'll leave this answer up because that's not obvious either.

Comment: Can you not swipe over to it? Admittedly the UI does not make it obvious that's possible, but that's nothing new.

Comment: Odd, I can repro the reported bug but not the one you say here about the missing site switcher.

Comment: @Laurel - Whattaya know, that works! Thanks, and I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda - The other post on this bug had screen shots from multiple sites, and I noticed that some were missing the switcher and some were not. >shrug<.